# where are my iOS simulators in xcode 6 after yosemite installation?

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode6, upgrade, osx-yosemite

I upgrade to Yosemite my Mini Mac (yesterday) and after a long hours (almost a day) the installation was succeeded.

I enter in my source code in Xcode 6.0.1 and after automatically install several things (i just saw the message and wait) i can't see the iOS simulators just iOS Device.

I check in Preferences but i have iOS Simulator 7.1 checked but i don't have any other simulator and i can't see 7.1 simulator either.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT ****
After install Xcode 6.1 I saw my iOS simulators again in Xcode. I saw a message "installed required components" when first launched the new Xcode version, so I supposed that fix it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the output of 'xcrun simctl list' ?

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia /* THIS IS THE OUTPUT */ == Device Types ==
iPhone 4s 
iPhone 5 
iPhone 5s 
iPhone 6 Plus 
iPhone 6 
iPad 2 
iPad Retina 
iPad Air 
Resizable iPhone 
Resizable iPad 
== Runtimes ==
iOS 7.0 (7.0.3 - 11B507) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-7-0) (unavailable, unsupported host version)
iOS 7.1 (7.1 - 11D167) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-7-1)
iOS 8.0 (8.0 - 12A365) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-0)
== Devices ==
-- iOS 7.0 --
-- iOS 7.1 --
-- iOS 8.0 --

Comment: Did you delete them?  They should be automatically created in ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices.  Does that path exist?  Do you have any subdirectories of that path or a ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/.default_created.plist file (which should list the devices that were created for you)?  Take a look at ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/*.log for any errors.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia Thanks, but after install Xcode 6.1 reappear all simulators. I don't know what happen but appear again.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In Xcode 6.1 you can add simulators manually. 
To do so go to Window -> Devices and press the + symbol left at the bottom.

[image: add a new simulator]

Then you can choose a combination of device type and iOS version to create.

[image: choose device type and iOS version]

if the iOS version you wanted is not there you'll be ask to download more simulator and directed to Xcode->Preference->Downloads.

[image]

**Note:** you can directly go to Xcode->Preference->Downloads and download more simulators and it will automatically available in simulator list after download.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I fixed after Xcode 6.1 installed but I will select this as an answer because is a great help to add any other iOS simulator.

Comment: This does not list the simulators for 7.0 and 8.0 on my box. Just updated to Yosemite, XCode deleted and freshly installed from MAS.

Comment: I deleted all directories of simulators in Library. I had to add all simulators again. Thank you.