# Using the device simulator for iOS 8 with Xcode 7

Tags: ios8, xcode7, ios9

I thinking about port my App to Swift 2 and Xcode 7. But the device simulator only targets iOS 9 and I see no way to download iOS 8.

I have parallel Xcode 6.3 installed. Is there any way to test and debug my app under iOS 8 with the device simulator?

Comment: Download iOS 8 simulator in Preferences > Downloads ?

Comment: Maybe this apply in Xcode 7 ... go to Window -> Devices and press the + symbol left at the bottom. (check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440023/where-are-my-ios-simulators-in-xcode-6-after-yosemite-installation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode release note says below thing,

> **Simulator**
>
> Xcode 7.0 beta does not support iOS 8.4 and earlier simulator
>   runtimes. (20699475)

Refer this [link](http://adcdownload.apple.com/WWDC_2015/Xcode_7_beta/Xcode_7_beta_Release_Notes.pdf) for more info.

Comment: the link shows me an error message but thank your for clarification. Now I have to maintain two different branches of my source code.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried that but for me it didnt work. no problem I have my answer.

Answer (score 18):

You can download older versions of iOS via Xcode.

Open

> Xcode -> Preferences -> Components -> Select

all the iOS versions you want ( iOS 8.4 )

Once downloaded, you can get to it in the

> Simulator -> Hardware -> Device

I am using Version 7.3.1 (7D1014)

Answer (score 3):

It can be used. You just need to find the file for the 8.x sdk that you want to test on in Xcode 6.x and copy it over to the corresponding Xcode 7 beta folder. You can find the file in this path.

Path: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

Xcode will suggest that you fix an error or two, but it should work. Note that when I did it there was still an error and some warnings, and I clicked run anyways and it worked regardless

You may need to click "other" and add "iphoneos8.x" (x is your version number)and if you have it added to the correct location it will work
.