# XCode 7 (Beta 3 & 4) Could not download and install iOS 8.* simulator

Tags: ios8, ios-simulator, xcode7

Trying to get iOS 8 simulators in XCode 7. Prior to beta 3, that wasn't possible but in beta 3 release notes:

> "Xcode 7.0 beta now supports downloadable legacy simulators."
>   [Xcode 7 beta 3 Release Notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7_beta_3/Xcode_7_beta_3_Release_Notes.pdf)

They also show up in the "Downloads" section:

[image: Downloads tab of Xcode 7 preferences]

I'm running into the same problem as reported in this [question about XCode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872040/installing-ios-simulator-8-3-8-4). I have Xcode 6 still installed, but am trying to install the simulator to Xcode 7 beta 3 where iOS 8 is no longer the base OS.

Error msg:

> Could not download and install iOS 8.3 simulator. Authorization is required to install the package

[image: Failed simulator install error message]

Comment: I've removed Xcode 6, restarted and am trying again...

Comment: That didn't help and reinstalling 7 didn't either

Comment: Please file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com including /var/log/system.log

Comment: I filed a radar - thanks @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia

Comment: What's the # for this radar?

Comment: @ThomasW mine was closed as a dupe of 21415111

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I found [another workaround on the Apple forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/51550#51550) for this issue that does not require downloading/having other versions of Xcode.  If you run Xcode using `sudo` the simulator downloads and installs work just fine:

```
sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
```

Note: Once the downloads and installs are complete you should quit Xcode and start it normally.

**Update:** XCool points out an important safety tip in the comments that I wanted to highlight here:

> Make sure that you close any projects before opening Xcode using sudo, otherwise there'll be a lot of permission issues with any files that are currently open when the installation occurs.

Comment: This sounds fantastic - verifying this is still an issue in build 7A220, and will try this as a simpler workaround

Comment: Bingo! still an issue in the app store version of Xcode 7, and this simple work around makes it possible to easily get iOS 8.* simulators. N.B. I had to restart my machine to get the simulator to load without error

Comment: Just like to highlight (for anyone stumbling upon this in the future). The above solution worked for me, but make sure that you close any projects before opening Xcode using sudo, otherwise there'll be a lot of permission issues with any files that are currently open when the installation occurs.

Comment: After installing this way once, I was able to install a simulator without using sudo. It might be that the UI needs to be active at the time the install is completing.

Answer (score 6):

sorry for the post, I don't have 50 reputation to comment. i am having this same issue. Any further progress? If I happen to come across a solution I will let you know. What have you tried?

--------- UPDATE -------

So I have found a work around.... if you are trying to get it to deploy to an iPhone.

If you still have the previous xCode file... you can navigate to Path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

copy the simulators and SDKS you want over to the same location in Xcode-beta.app and paste... granted those downloads still won't download, but this will allow for the simulator to run on your iPhone.

I got this from [Using the device simulator for iOS 8 with Xcode 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30837272/using-the-device-simulator-for-ios-8-with-xcode-7?rq=1)

and verified it works.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround @Tory - holding out for a full solution, but guessing that will come in the next beta version. Fingers crossed!

Comment: yeah the problem was,  I got impatient and started working on something for work, that then needed a demo two days from when I did this. Had to find a workaround. lol

Comment: Beta 4 slipped through while I was away last week - will be trying with that, and if that doesn't work, I'll try your workaround. Thanks @Tory

Comment: Really? Can you post pics of the folder structure? I can tell you what to do. I also have an update to this I will add as well.

Comment: Sorry, haven't tried your work around - was just saying didn't work in Beta 4. I don't have the previous xCode files

Comment: I will upload them somewhere and paste a link along with the symlinks you will need. if that works. I am at my office.

Comment: Show package content on code-beta. go to Developer > Platforms > iPhoneSimulator.platform > Developer > SDKs

Once there. create a symlink for the SDKS you need. to the iPhoneOS.sdk


For example, I have iPhoneOS8.1.sdk pointed there... Once that is done inside of your app settings set the deployment target, go to build settings and change the sdk to what you want with the naming convention like `iphoneos8.1` and then the app can be run on your iPhone. 

I am not sure how far back that temp fix will go... but I know it works back to 8.1. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

XCode 7 and above does not support simulators 8.4 and earlier.
Please check my answer on the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872040/xcode-6-4-could-not-download-and-install-ios-8-3-simulator/33794820#33794820).