# how to replicate ios versions iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, crash

I have been a bunch of crash reports and have pinpointed that the reason for these crashes are because of the version of the iPhone is iOS 7 and below. Is there a way to replicate the version or change the version on the simulator?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440023/where-are-my-ios-simulators-in-xcode-6-after-yosemite-installation the answer show how can add simulators in Xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode preferences -> Downloads

You'll find the components list, in which you can download iOS 7.1 simulator.

The older simulators runtimes are not compatible with the new CoreSimulator architecture. That means that if you want to test in older versions (7.0, 6.0 for example) you will need to downgrade your XCode.

Hope it Helps.

Answer (score 1):

While in Xcode go to "Window -> Devices". Add a simulator using the bottom '+' key.

It will bring up a window with options for the type of iPhone and IOS version number.

Once you add the device you will be able to run your app on that simulator with the selected IOS version.